# How exactly the Firebase realtime database usually charge?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have this chat functionality in my app. I am retrieving messages like this:

```
 private void loadmessage(String class_id, String email_red) {
            DatabaseReference messageRef = mRootRef.child("Announcement").child(email_red).child(class_id);
            messageRef.keepSynced(true);

            messageRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    String messageKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class).withID(messageKey);
                    messageList.add(message);
                    keyList.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mMessagesList.scrollToPosition(messageList.size() - 1);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    String messageKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class).withID(messageKey);
                    int index = keyList.indexOf(messageKey);
                    messageList.set(index, message);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    int index = keyList.indexOf(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    messageList.remove(index);
                    keyList.remove(index);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
```

As you can see I have used `messageRef.keepSynced(true);` for the offline feature.

Now lets say there can be 100-200 messages(only text) at max and I am putting each of them in the `RecyclerView`.

Now my question is: Every time the user opens this activity, firebase will get those 200 messages from database again or is it once? How will I be getting charged on this?

And lastly, putting 200 messages(only text) in the recyclerView is fine? Or should I use pagination?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you directly contacted Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see I have used messageRef.keepSynced(true); for the offline feature.

If you want be able to query your the database even if you are offline, you should use the following line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

And not `messageRef.keepSynced(true);` as you say you do now. When using the above line of code, you tell Firebase to create a local copy of your database.

> Every time the user opens this activity, firebase will get those 200 messages from database again or is it once?

If you are calling `loadmessage()` method everytime you start an activity, it means that you are adding a `ChildEventListener` on your `messageRef` object. If you want to get the data only once, you should use a `ListenerForSingleValueEvent`, which means that the listener will read the data **precisely** once. That means that your `onDataChange()` method gets triggered with the current value (from the cache if available, otherwise from Firebase servers), and stop listening immediately after that.

> How will I be getting charged on this?

According to [Firebase Pricing Plans](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).

> And lastly, putting 200 messages(only text) in the recyclerView is fine? Or should I use pagination?

It's good that you decided to use a `RecyclerView` rather than a simple `ListView` to display the messages because the views are constantly recycled. In case of 200 messages, I recommend you to implement pagination, to load data in smaller chuncks, let let's say 10 or 15 messages at the time. Maybe you'll be interested in reading ony 30 messages, why to download all of them?

Comment: Very well answered. Now I am using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`. Now as you can see I have 3 methods namely `onChildAdded()`, `onChildChanged()`, `onChildRemoved()`. If I use `ListenerForSingleValueEvent` I won't have these methods. So will I be able to perform actions such as delete and edit?

Comment: "If I use ListenerForSingleValueEvent I won't have these methods.". Yes, that's correct. You'll have only one (`onDataChange()`), that will handle all those events for you. Yes, you'll be able.